# facebook like buttons not letting users enter text

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a site with a facebook like button (using iframe). when a user clicks there's a small popup and the user can enter text.

I have another site with exactly the same code, but when the users likes there is no popup to enter text...

How is that?

This is the code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxxxxxx.org&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=recommend&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;appId=xxxxxxx" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

When will users have the option to add a comment to the like?

If you are using the XFBML version of the Like button, users will always have the option to add a comment. If you are using the Iframe version of the button, users will have the option to comments if you are using the 'standard' layout with a width of at least 400 pixels. If users do add a comment, the story published back to Facebook is given more prominence.

Comment: that's strange, because they were the same code... i'll keep trying... thanks anyway